# Highcharts: Reset zoom in steps based on previous selected zoom levels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm very new to software dev and even newer to highcharts.  At present the reset zoom button just resets the view based on the initial min and max dates fed in.

What I would like to do comes in two stages:

1. push() the event.min and event.max to an array on each zoom/pinch.
2. Pressing the 'reset zoom' button will then grab the event.min event.max from the array, pop() it from the array and revert the zoom level to the previous 'stage'.

I have no problems storing the min/max values but any ideas at all on how to rewire the reset button would be much appreciated.

Do you guys reckon this is possible or is the button locked down?

Thanking you all in advance,

David

Comment: You can add custom button in this case, using chart.renderer.button() method: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.button

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As you're suggesting using a custom button, does that mean that what I'm attempting can't be hacked in to the existing button?

I'll look in to chart.renderer.button() just now - thanks again

Comment: I thought about adding new button to your chart but you should be able to wrap the standard resetZoom button as well.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for your input.  I'll go and start looking at how to wrap the existing button.  It's not time sensitive so I've got a bit of time to play around with it.